# Error training custom dataset with Detectron2

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, detectron

I am trying to train a custom data for image segmentation with Detectron2, but I have an issue while using the config files (like mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml).

Here is the the configuration that I use for training:

```
cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = "cpu"
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("category_train",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()

cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"

cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 0
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 8
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.00025  # pick a good LR

cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 25000
cfg.SOLVER.STEPS = []
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 512
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 6
```

The part where I get error is cfg.merge_from_file() part. If I remove it and cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS, then the code works and model successfully trains the object detection model. I need image segmentation, so I need to use these configurations.

However, using them gives the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets\\coco/annotations/instances_train2017.json'`

I looked in the Detectron2 issues and someone also had the same error, and the solution was to put the following in code:

`cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()`

However, I had already done that, and it did not help me. Does anyone have any ideas on why this could not work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

check the path to the file `instances_train2017.json`, there is a problem with the path to that file, `datasets\\coco/annotations/instances_train2017.json` is not the correct path. please check the configuration within this file `COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml` I hope you will see that line inside.

Comment: This file has only following pieces of addresses, and none are referring to the above address: 
`_BASE_: "../Base-RCNN-FPN.yaml"`

`MODEL:
  WEIGHTS: "detectron2://ImageNetPretrained/MSRA/R-50.pkl"`

Comment: have you checked inside that address too?